# Meteor: how pass context to another event handler

Tags: javascript, meteor

I click on element with class "forma" and then create a window in which i click element with class "update-task". And in that event handler this == undefined. 
Tell me please how pass context from ".forma event" to ".update-task event"

```
Template.myTemp.events({
 'click .forma': function() { 
    console.log(this._id); //show id
 }, 
 'click .update-task': function() { 
    console.log(this._id); //is undefined 
 } 
});
```

This is code from my template

```html
<ul>
  {{#each tasks}}
  <li>
    <i class="{{#if completed}} checked {{/if}} complete-task zmdi zmdi-badge-check" data-check="false" title="This task is completed"></i>
    <i class="{{#if priority}} checked {{/if}} priority-task zmdi zmdi-star-outline" data-check="false" title="Set high priority"></i>
    <i class="forma {{#if completed}} completed-task {{/if}}">{{task}}</i>
    <i class="delete-task zmdi zmdi-delete" title="Delete this task"></i>
    <!-- <i class="edit-task zmdi zmdi-edit"></i> -->
  </li>
  <hr>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
<div class="edit-popup-form">
  <form class="edit-task-form">
    <input id="edit-task" type="text" name="task" placeholder="Enter new task here..." autofocus required>
    <button type="submit">
      <i class="update-task zmdi zmdi-file-plus" title="Update current task"></i>
    </button>
    <i class="close-popup-form zmdi zmdi-close" title="Close this form"></i>
  </form>
```

in this code i click on "task-content" and then see "edit-popup-form" in which click "add-task"(lost context)

Sorry for the dirty formatting of the code

Comment: please show your code for the template where .update-task lives

Comment: add template code to description

Comment: maybe I'm blind, but I don't see `update-task` anywhere in that code.

Comment: rewrite code. Class "forma" in ul tag, and "update-task" in lives in <div class="edit-popup-form">

Comment: it seems you have a modal (popup?) that you reuse for all tasks. But I don't see how you trigger that popup. Whereever you do that you will need to pass the "this" data context. Alternatively you need to move the update-task button inside the #each, where it will now what `this` refers to (the task).

Comment: when i click on class .forma i call popup(edit-popup-form) and then i want click .update-task which make update in DB, but in popup context is lost. How i can pass context to popup?  i put my popup in #each how you say and context was be received. But why context is saved at the first click, and then used the same. I think the reason is that how I work with popup

Answer (score 0):

I use ReactiveVar for my template and it works nice
 Christian Fritz thanks for help)